# bind class functions vs util functions

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, bind

I've been wondering what would be the better to declare pure functions. And if there is a drawback with declaring them as an util functions. So:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export const exampleFunction = () => {

};

class ExampleComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const useExampleFunction = exampleFunction();
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

ExampleComp.propTypes = {};

export default ExampleComp;
```

VS.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';


class ExampleComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.exampleFunction = this.exampleFunction.bind(this);
  }

  exampleFunction() {

  }

  render() {
    const useExampleFunction = this.exampleFunction();
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

ExampleComp.propTypes = {};

export default ExampleComp;
```

Also if we declare this function as a static method of ExampleComp class, would it better practice to export the function as a static class property?

Comment: If you passed the `useExampleFunction` (that hasn't received the `.bind(this)`) to a sub component via a prop it would lose it's context. i.e. the `this` will change.

Comment: Thats because under the hood your jsx get translated to objects so the function would be attached to a "new" object.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of `exampleFunction`. If it's a utility function and you declare it externally, you get the benefit of making is reusable. However, if it's really component-specific and you need to access the instance itself (`this`), you would probably declare it inside the class and bind.

Comment: Since you're always calling `this.exampleFunction();` and not passing the function around, there's no need to do `this.exampleFunction = this.exampleFunction.bind(this);` in the constructor. Omit it.